# PHP preg_match a specific pattern in hostname

Tags: php, arrays, preg-match

I have hostnames given below and I want to preg_match a specific pattern.

**Hostnames:**

```
sub1.hostname1.com
sub12.hostname2.com
suboo2.hostname3.com
sub2.hostname4.com
```

**Desired Output** after preg_match:

```
sub1.hostname1.com
suboo2.hostname3.com
sub2.hostname4.com
```

The idea is to get hostnames that have a **`1`** or **`2`** in the subdomain.

Comment: have you tried anything? if yes put your code

Comment: No i haven't struggling with it. I got a sed based regex match but that doesn't work for php.

Comment: For an array try `preg_grep`.

Comment: If I could just match one string at a time. I don't need even need to solve this problem for an array. Example: $str = "sub1.hostname1.com";  if(preg_match("pattern????", $str)) { echo "yay! found the pattern"; }

Comment: then if that's the case , using `strpos` will do the trick?

Comment: Will that work for sub12.hostname.com???? Using strpos I can try finding "1" and the condition will be true. But I am only looking for the subdomains with 1 and 2. eg. subsomelongstring1.hostname.com, subdomainssssss2.hostname.com

Comment: Your filtering criteria is unclear. Give "1 or 2", that should match "sub12". You need to clarify what you actually want to do here

Comment: ok. so lets say I have "subdomain1.hostname.com" and "anothersubdomain12.hostname.com". After regex or preg_match I only want "subdomain1.hostname.com". Now another senario is with "subdomain2.hostname.com" and "anothersubdomain12.hostname.com". After preg_match I only want "subdomain1.hostname.com"

Comment: Don't just give examples of what you want; **describe** the problem. What is the **criteria** that should be used to validate a hostname? Right now, it looks like you want to match on "the first hostname segment must end in 1 or 2 but not both". Is this right?

Comment: I want all hostnames that have subdomains with exactly "1" or "2" in them.

Comment: Anywhere *"in them"* or just at the end? How many occurrences? Like I said before, "1 or 2" **will match** "sub12"

Comment: yes. 1 occurrence, "IN THEM".

Comment: @basic1point0 I doubt that very much

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you had a paper and a pen, and you were asked to write down a simple algorithm that does this, how would you do it?

This is how I would do it:

1. You can determine where the sub-domain is, in the string, by finding the first dot. So, find the first dot and then extract the subdomain.
2. Since we are only interested in the numbers we can, logically, remove anything that is not a number.
3. Now we only have a number, and it should be pretty simple to evaluate if it is what we want.

In code, you could do something like this:

```
$samples = [
    'sub1.hostname1.com',
    'sub12.hostname2.com',
    'suboo2.hostname3.com',
    'sub2.hostname4.com',
];
foreach ($samples as $domain) {

    // Find the sub-domain
    $dot = strpos($domain, '.');
    if ($dot === false) {
        continue;
    }
    $sub = substr($domain, 0, $dot);

    // Remove non-numbers from the sub-domain
    $number = filter_var($sub, FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);

    // Check that it is what we want
    if ($number == 1 or $number == 2) {
        echo "$domain is a $number sub-domain<br>";
    }
}
```

I will leave it as an exercise to throw that into a function, if this is what you are looking for.

If you absolutely want to use a regular expressions then it would just be a matter of checking the sub-domain for the number:

```
foreach ($samples as $domain) {
    $matches = preg_match('/^[^0-9]+(?:1|2)\./', $domain);
    if ($matches === 1) {
        echo "$domain is a 1 or 2 sub-domain<br>";
    }
}
```

Comment: Your regex isn't going to work for subdomains that **start with** a number. In fact, it will only work with ones that **end with** 1 or 2

Comment: @Phil I know. I based my answer on the examples given in the question; they only *end* with numbers. If the questioner wants to match a more complicated pattern then they need to explain it more thoroughly.

Comment: OP explains it better in the comments. Also, your check will fail on any number sequence equating to a number not equal to 1 or 2. For example, `sub32` which meets the condition *"has only one occurrence of a 1 or 2"*

Comment: @Phil I only check for `1` and `2`. If you want to check for `32` then it is just a matter of adding it to the `if` expression, or the regex `OR` sequence. The OP obviously finds this answer useful, so I do not get what your problem is.

Comment: I don't have a problem but OP might when they encounter sub-domains with other numbers in them

Comment: @Phil Yes, well, then they should have mentioned that they needed a more flexible solution. The most effective answers, I have found,  are those that contain the minimum amount of code possible to solve the problem. If that is not enough then you can always add to it later.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds more like you want to *filter* the array. Try this...

```
$filtered = array_filter($hostnames, function($hostname) {
    // assume that the "subdomain" is the first hostname segment, separated by "."
    list($subdomain, $theRest) = explode('.', $hostname, 2);

    return preg_match_all('/1|2/', $subdomain) === 1;
});
```

Demo here - http://ideone.com/MwbS7T

Answer (score 0):

Your question is rather unclear, but from the comments I could extract the following meaning:

> Match a sub domain which contains exactly one '1' or exactly one '2', but not both

That requirement translates to this code:

```
$subdom = strstr($host, '.', true);

$matched = substr_count($subdom, '1') == 1 ^ substr_count($subdom, '2') == 1;
```

The `^` (xor) operator makes sure that a sub domain with both '1' and '2' is not counted.